# Configure Python Flask RESTplus app via TOML file

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

Based on the [Configuration Handling Documents for Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/) the section of [Configuring from Files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-files) mentions a possibility to configure the App using files however it provides no example or mention of files that are not *Python Files*.

Is it possible to configure apps via files like `config.yml` or `config.toml`?

My Current flask app has configurations for two distinct databases and since I am using `flask-restplus` there are additional configurations for Swagger documentations.

**Snippet**:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def configure_app(flask_app):

    # MongoDB Setting
    flask_app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://user:password@mongo_db_endpoint:37018/myDB?authSource=admin'
    flask_app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'myDB'

    # InfluxDB Setting
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_HOST'] = 'my_influxdb_endpoint'
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_PORT'] = 8086
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_USER'] = 'influx_user'
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_PASSWORD'] = 'influx_password'
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_SSL'] =  True
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_VERIFY_SSL'] = False
    flask_app.config['INFLUXDB_DATABASE'] = 'IoTData'

    # Flask-Restplus Swagger Configuration
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION'] = 'list'
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_VALIDATE'] = True
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = False
    flask_app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = False

def main():
    configure_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

I would like to avoid setting large number of Environment Variables and wish to configure them using a `config.toml` file?

How is this achieved in `flask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.cfg` files and `from_envvar` to achieve this. Create config file with all your environment variables.

my_config.cfg

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://user:password@mongo_db_endpoint:37018
..
..
ERROR_404_HELP=False
```

Then set the env var `APP_ENVS=my_config.cfg`. Now all you need to do is use from_envvars given by Flask.

```py
def configure_app(flask_app):
    flask_app.config.from_envvar('APP_ENVS')
    # configure any other things
    # register blue prints if you have any
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/#configuring-from-data-files):

> ### Configuring from Data Files
>
> It is also possible to load configuration from a file in a format of
> your choice using `from_file()`. For example to load from a TOML file:
>
> ```
> import toml
> app.config.from_file("config.toml", load=toml.load)
> ```
>
> Or from a JSON file:
>
> ```
> import json
> app.config.from_file("config.json", load=json.load)
> ```

EDIT: The above feature is new for v2.0.

Link to the documentation reference:

Class `Flask.config`, method [`from_file(filename, load, silent=False)`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Config.from_file)

Comment: Seems like this is now available for Docs 2.x, whereas at the time of posting this query my links pointed to `1.1.x`, maybe can you add this as a note?

Comment: Sure, edited as above.